# jquery delete cookies only when site is closed

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery

when the site opens, I open a modal . When the site is closed, I want to delete the cookies. I tried the codes below, but when the page is refreshed, the modal opens again. How can I delete cookies only when the site is closed. thanks

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    if ($.cookie("announcement") == null) {
        $.cookie("announcement", "yes");
        $("#large").modal("show");
    }
});

function cookieDelete() {
    $.removeCookie("announcement");
}

$(window).on("beforeunload", function () {
    cookieDelete();
    return;
});
```

Comment: you could use [session storage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/sessionStorage) instead of a cookie as it only persists for as long as the browser tab is open

Comment: Any special reason for `cookies`? what about `session storage`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If **Cookie** is not a requirement, I suggest an alternate solution using [Session Storage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/sessionStorage)

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    const announcement = sessionStorage.getItem("announcement");
    if (!announcement) {
        sessionStorage.setItem("announcement", "yes");
        $("#large").modal("show");
    }
});
```

You don't need to handle `delete` operation because `session storage` will be cleared automatically when the page is closed.

Comment: Do I need cdn or something else to use sessionStorage?

Comment: No No, it is completely stored in your browser.

Comment: I get this error in console: " Uncaught TypeError: sessionStorage.get is not a function "

Comment: I am sorry, It should be `getItem()` and `setItem()`. I updated my answer

Comment: Just an advisory:  sessionStorage can't be used if the document is "sandboxed" (eg in an SO snippet).  It's unlikely this will be a problem for most websites.

Comment: Thanks for your time. The document is not a sandbox. I just show the announcement modal every time the user logs in.

Answer (score 0):

You have to delete the cookie on **.unload** event

```
$(window).unload(function() {
    cookieDelete();
});
```

Comment: I guess unload is not working because of jquery version

Comment: which version of Jquery are you using?

Comment: jquery-3.4.1 I am using version

Comment: @AjayGupta why do you think `unload` event won't be triggered whilst page reloading?

Comment: because I want it to appear in front of the user once